# Hasura Graphql- How to pass Output of one Query as an input to the other Query?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I am new to Postgres DB and Hasura-Graphql.
It would be good if anyone can help me out.

So there are two tables, Table1 with( username, email, id, table1id) and Table2 with (username, email, booksRead, visitedLocations, table2_id). These two tables are not connected( either by PK or FK).

Now the question is I have to query from table1 to get uername and email with that I need to query table2. So is there anyway where I can add output of one query as the input to the another query in the one query.

Also note that I need to go from table1 to table2 for some other details.

For example:

```
query{
 table1{
   username,
   email
 }
 table2(where:{username:username, email:email}){
   username,
   email,
   visitedLocations,
   booksRead
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [table relationships](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/table-relationships/index.html) or [custom functions](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/custom-functions.html).

What you want to do is not very clear, but I think you should redesign your database schema:

- user table with PK
- visitedLocations with one to many relationship with user table
- booksRead with one to many relationship with user table

So, querying could be:

```
query {
    user {
        username
        email
        visitedLocations {
            location
        }
        booksRead {
            book
        }
    }

}
```